# Chrome devtools for android development, inspect devices failing

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

I can't get `chrome://inspect/#devices` to allow inspection of my devices. It successfully detects my Android 5 phone, but it does not offer an `inspect` link. I'm using a mac for android app development. USB debugging is enabled. I've tried the USB connection as a camera and as a media device. Nothing works. Has anyone else had this problem recently?